# R plot with dense and sparse values

Tags: r, plot

How would I go about plotting X and Y based on Count from the given table? I don't think I can use plot() here.

```
X    Y    Count
-----------------
1    1       10
1    2        5
2    1       15
2    2       10
```

Other than just putting all the occurrences of X and Y in a table, how would I plot a graph from the given table?

Comment: This is pretty open ended; you can visualize it any number of ways. I'd probably opt for a heatmap, depending on the interpretation of `X` and `Y`. (Also assuming that this is a small toy example of a larger problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming X and Y are factors with only a couple of values, the most simple way is this:

```
 data <- data.frame(X = c(1,1,2,2),
                   Y = c(1,2,1,2),
                   "Count" = c(10,5,15,10))

 data$X <- as.factor(data$X) 
 data$Y <- as.factor(data$Y)

 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Count, fill = Y)) +
                geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge())
```

or

```
 data <- data.frame(X = c(1,1,2,2),
                   Y = c(1,2,1,2),
                   "Count" = c(10,5,15,10))

 data$X <- as.factor(data$X) 
 data$Y <- as.factor(data$Y)

 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Count)) +
                geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
facet_wrap(~Y)
```